# C programm to find middle number

Tags: c

Hi this is my code to find the middle number of three but when i give a=3 b=2 and c=1 i get wrong output.How can i find the right middle number?Is there any way with arrays?
thank you

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()

{

    int a,b,c;

    int min,mid,max,i=1;

    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("\nEnter number: ");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    printf("\nEnter number: ");
    scanf("%d",&c);

    if(((a<b)&&(b<c)) || ((a>b)&&(a<c)))
    {
        min=a;
        mid=b;
        max=c;
    }
    if(((b<a)&&(a>c)) || ((a>b)&&(a<c)))
    {
        min=c;
        mid=a;
        max=b;
    }
    if(((c<a)&&(c>b)) || ((c>a)&&(c<b)))
    {
        min=b;
        mid=c;
        max=a;
    }
    printf("\nMid is %d",mid);



    for(i=min;i<=max;i++)
    {


        if(i==mid)
            continue;
        printf("\n%d",i);
    }

    getchar();
    getchar();

}
```

Comment: Your second part of the first condition is wrong. Haven't checked the others, you can do it yourself.

Comment: Take a step back. After you parse `min`, `mid`, and `max`, __Print them out!__. For example, with `3 2 1`, you'll notice that `min == 3` and `max == 1`, which is backwards.

Comment: `man qsort`.  That's how you do it with an array.

Answer (score 1):

To make your life easier, write a function called `min`. It takes two integers and returns the one which is smaller. Now use this function like this:

```
int min = min(min(a,b),c);
```

Similar with max.

To get the mid value, just make this calculation:

```
int mid = a + b + c - max - min;
```

Comment: You mean the code of min and max? Something like that: `if (a < b) return a; else return b` If you mean how will the whole code look like (that you posted): You have to integrate that yourself. I just showed you how you will get to know min, mid and max

Answer (score 1):

If you have a sorted array:

```
int nums[N];
```

Then:

- For N even the median is: `(nums[N/2] + nums[(N/2)-1])/2`
- For N odd the median is: `nums[(N-1)/2]`

If your array is not sorted, then check the [Median of Medians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians)

Answer (score 0):

if you are able to find maximum and minimum values, you can find the middle value like this:

```
int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
int minVal = min(a, b);
int maxVal = max(maxVal, c);

int midVal = a + b + c - maxVal - minVal;
```

midVal should contain the middle value of those 3 numbers.

Comment: You are using `maxVal` in `max()` but it's undefined

Answer (score 0):

Sorting with an array is pretty simple:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int compar( const void *a, const void *b)
{
        return *(int*)a > *(int*)b;
}

void die(const char *msg)
{
        if( errno )
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", strerror(errno), msg);
        else
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int get_input(void)
{
        int ret;
        errno = 0;
        if( scanf("%d", &ret ) != 1 )
                die("invalid input");
        return ret;
}

void * xmalloc(size_t s)
{
        void *ret;
        ret = malloc(s);
        if(ret == NULL)
                die("malloc");
        return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int *a;
        int *b;
        int count;
        count = get_input();
        a = b = xmalloc( count * sizeof *a);
        while(count-- > 0)
                *b++ = get_input();

        qsort(a, b - a, sizeof *a, compar);
        printf("sorted:");
        while(a != b)
                printf(" %d", *a++);
        putchar('\n');
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int a,b,c;
if(b>a && a>c || c>a && a>b) 
    printf("The middle number is a");
else if(a>b && b>c || c>b && b>a) 
    printf("The middle number is b"); 
else
    printf("The middle number is c");
```

Comment: Breaks if `a == b` (e.g., `int a = 2, b = 2, c = 3;`) where the output is `c`.

Answer (score -1):

#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

```
int a,b,c,mid;

printf("Enter a: ");
scanf("%d",&a);

printf("Enter b: ");
scanf("%d",&b);

printf("Enter c: ");
scanf("%d",&c);

if( ( a>b && b>c ) || ( c>b && b>a ) ){
mid=b;

}

else if(( a>c && c>b )||( b>c && c>a )){
mid=c;

}

else
{mid=a;
}

printf("The middle is %d",mid);
```

}